# Android timepicker - similar to this in the Alarms app

Tags: android, android-timepicker

In the android alarms app I have a dialog datepicker that has a keypad (image attached):

[image]

is that a standard timepicker? because I couldn't find how to do it. I found the TimePickerDialog - but that is no a keypad.

Is there a property that I'm missing or a library that does that kind of timepicker dialog?

Thanks

Comment: No, it's a custom one. It looks incredibly similar to a [betterpickers](https://github.com/derekbrameyer/android-betterpickers) one.

Answer (score 0):

see this answer i have already given for this type of pickers :)

> [Implementing New styled date&time-pickers from android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23921436/implementing-new-styled-datetime-pickers-from-android/24114375#24114375)