# Implementing New styled date&time-pickers from android

Tags: android, android-datepicker, android-timepicker

[`I was going through android official blog site here`](http://officialandroid.blogspot.ca/2013/05/google-calendar-update-for-android.html):: I found out new type of date and time pickers showcased in android

---

**Questions**::

1. I am familiar with implementing old styled widgets, but how to implement this new widgets
2. Any samplecode on how to implement this styled widgets
3. Minimum level API required to implement these styles

---

[image]

Comment: [DateTimePicker](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/opt/datetimepicker/+/master) They're part of a library project. You use them by calling `DatePickerDialog.newInstance` or `TimePickerDialog.newInstance`.

Comment: @adneal ..... i have implemented these widgets but i dont get this styled widgets. I am using API-14 ..... Is it so that these new style is only available for higher api like 19 ?

Comment: Are you sure you're implementing `com.android.datetimepicker.time.TimePickerDialog` and not `android.app.TimePickerDialog`? API level 14 is the min SDK version.

Comment: @adneal .... Ahh ! ... i was not using the com.android.datetimepicker.time.TimePickerDialog ... now i understand ... thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Q1.Ans** now its Library available see this thanks to @derekbrameyer

> https://github.com/derekbrameyer/android-betterpickers

and live preview on play see

> https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.doomonafireball.betterpickers.sample

**Q2.Ans** library shipped with sample

**Q3.Ans** i am running this app on 2.3 devise (API level 8)and its working perfectly

Comment: I f u r using this Library for API-8 ...how you resolved the font error that pops up in library when i import library to eclipse .... how did u resolve it ?